# DynamoDB BatchGetItem dynamic TableName in Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

I'm building a serverless backend for my current application using dynamoDb as my database. I use aws sam to upload my lambda functions to aws. In addition, I pass all my table names as global variables to lambda (nodejs8.10 runtime) to access them on the `process.env` object within my lambda function. The problem that I'm facing with this is the following: Whenever I run the `batchGetItem` method on dynamoDB I have to pass a string as my table name, I cannot dynamically change the table name depending on the global variable:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({region: 'ap-south-1'}, {apiVersion:'2012-08-10'});

const params = {
    RequestItems: {
        //needs to be a string, cannot be a variable containing a string
        'tableName': {
            Keys: [] //array of keys
         }
    }
}
dynamodb.batchGetItem(params, (err, result) => {
// some logic
})
```

I need to pass the table name as a string, essentially hardcoding the table name into my function. Other DynamoDB operations, like for example the `getItem` method, accept a key value pair for the table name in the parameter object:

```
const tableName = process.env.TableName;
const getItemParams = {
   Key: {
        "Key": {
             S: 'some key'
         }
   },
   // table name can be changed according to the value past to lambda's environment variable
   TableName: tableName
}
dynamodb.getItem(getItemParams, (err, result) => {
// some logic
}
```

Hence my question, is there any way to avoid hardcoding the table name in the `batchGetItem` method and, instead, allocate it dynamically like in the `getItem` method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `tableName` from environment variables. Build your params in 2 steps :

```
const { tableName } = process.env;

const params = {
  RequestItems: {},
};

// `tableName` is your environment variable, it may have any value
params.RequestItems[tableName] = {
  Keys: [], //array of keys
};

dynamodb.batchGetItem(params, (err, result) => {
  // some logic
})
```

Comment: hey @costin , can you suggest me best tutorial for aws lambda

Comment: @pyd There is no best tutorial, the best is the one that helps you advance. Read the docs and practice, this is the only way you can progress. • [AWS Lambda Resources](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/resources/), • [API Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Reference.html), etc. • Read blogs and questions, and, most important, fully understand what the options are in the AWS Lambda console. Good luck!